# onNavigationItemSelected not being called

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I made an Android Studio project with the basic drawer generated. However, the onNavigationItemSelected function is never called.

My objective is to change the fragment in the activity when you choose a different option in the menu, but currently it only shows my ControllerFragment (the one I put in the XML file), and never changes it.

Here is my code :

MainActivity.java

```
package com.dylem.robotremotev2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        System.out.println("0");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        System.out.println("1"); // NOT CALLED
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.param_connexion) {

        } else if (id == R.id.piloter_robot) {
            System.out.println("2");
            final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.controller_fragment, new ControllerFragment());
            ft.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.trajets_enregistres) {
            final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.drawer_layout, new ParcoursFragment());
            ft.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nouveau_trajet) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/controller_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        class="com.dylem.robotremotev2.ControllerFragment" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Robot Remote v2.0"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="yolo@github.io" />

</LinearLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.dylem.robotremotev2.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

activity_main_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/piloter_robot"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Piloter le robot" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/trajets_enregistres"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Trajets enregistrés" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nouveau_trajet"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Nouveau Trajet" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/param_connexion"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Paramètres de connexion" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

ControllerFragment.java

```
package com.dylem.robotremotev2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

// Nouvelle activité
public class ControllerFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener, View.OnClickListener {

/*
    Contains the commands to send to the DB
    Map<Key, [Arrow, Time]>
 */
private Map<Integer, ControllerAction> commands = new HashMap<>();
private char direction = 'S';
private boolean started = false;
private Chronometer chrono;
private long actionChrono = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.controller_layout, container, false);

    final ImageButton[] arrows = {
            view.findViewById(R.id.up),
            view.findViewById(R.id.left),
            view.findViewById(R.id.right),
            view.findViewById(R.id.down)
    };

    for(final ImageButton arrow : arrows) {
        arrow.setBackgroundResource(getButtonResource(arrow, false));
        arrow.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    view.findViewById(R.id.start_course).setOnClickListener(this);
    chrono = (Chronometer) view.findViewById(R.id.simpleChronometer);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if(v instanceof ImageButton) {
        if (!(event.getAction() == (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP))) { // PENDANT
            v.setBackgroundResource(getButtonResource(v, true));
            this.direction = getButtonDirection(v);
            if(this.started)
                this.actionChrono = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        } else { // APRES
            if (this.started) {
                final ControllerAction action = new ControllerAction(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - this.actionChrono, this.direction);
                this.commands.put(this.commands.size(), action);
            }

            v.setBackgroundResource(getButtonResource(v, false));
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v.getId() == R.id.start_course) {
        Button b = (Button)v;
        this.started = !this.started;
        this.chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

        if(this.started) {
            b.setText("Terminer le parcours");
            this.chrono.start();
        }
        else {
            b.setText("Commencer un parcours");
            this.chrono.stop();
            sendActions();
        }
    }
}

public void sendActions() {

    Iterator it = this.commands.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        ControllerAction action = (ControllerAction) pair.getValue();
        Log.d("DEBUG : ", pair.getKey() + " -> action : " + action.getAction() + ", temps : " + action.getTimeIn());
    }
}

public char getButtonDirection(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.up:
            return 'W';
        case R.id.left:
            return 'A';
        case R.id.right:
            return 'D';
        case R.id.down:
            return 'S';
        default:
            return 'O';
    }
}

/*
    Envoie l'action à effectuer en fonction du bouton appuyé.
    @Param v la vue
    @Param pressed si le bouton est appuyé ou non
    @Return la nouvelle ressource à utiliser
 */
public int getButtonResource(View v, boolean pressed) {

    int r = 0; // ressource à retourner

    if(pressed) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.up:
                r = R.drawable.up_c;
                break;
            case R.id.left:
                r = R.drawable.left_c;
                break;
            case R.id.right:
                r = R.drawable.right_c;
                break;
            case R.id.down:
                r = R.drawable.down_c;
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.up:
                r = R.drawable.up;
                break;
            case R.id.left:
                r = R.drawable.left;
                break;
            case R.id.right:
                r = R.drawable.right;
                break;
            case R.id.down:
                r = R.drawable.down;
                break;
        }
    }

    return r;
}
}
```

Comment: The drawer - your `NavigationView` - needs to be listed last inside the `DrawerLayout` in the `activity_main` layout. Everything else should be above it, inside one `ViewGroup`.

Comment: DrawerLayout only can have 2 child. One is main content view and another one is navigation view. Change your controller_fragment and Relative layout inside app_bar_layout. then it will work

Comment: Thanks, it works now ! :)